# LINQ to SQL - ToDictionary not supported - How do I pull results into memory?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

```
  var details= from row in databaseTable
    where row.id equals queryId
    select new 
     {
       Dict = row.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value),
     };
```

When executing this LINQ to SQL I get the error;

> System.NotSupportedException: The
>   query operator 'ToDictionary' is not
>   supported.

What I need to do is pull the rows into memory first but I'm not sure how. I tried calling ToList in various places but had no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var fixTotaliserDetails = (from row in databaseTable
                           where row.id == queryId
                           select new 
                           {
                             row.Name,
                             row.Value,
                           })
                          .ToDictionary(x=>x.Name, x=>x.Value);
```

This will work. I think you may have over-simplified your answer though, since in linq-to-sql an item in a table doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Just beat me to it.  The key here is that you need to first pull the data back, and then you translate it into a dictionary.  It has to come back from the DB as raw data and then be modified to fit the OO perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try?

```
var fixTotaliserDetails = (from row in databaseTable
    where row.id equals queryId
    select name = x.Name, value = x.Value).ToDictionary(x => x.name);
```

and if you want to search by value, then change `.ToDictionary(x => x.name);` by `.ToDictionary(x => x.value);`.

Hope this helps.